# php://input and file_get_contents just output the POST data rather than process it

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I have the following snippet of code. For the URL QueryString, I am passing in `php://input`. In the body of the request I am passing in `<?php echo "ABC";?>`

```
$image_url=$_GET['URL'];
$data = file_get_contents($image_url);
$new = 'images/TEST.jpg';
$upload = file_put_contents($new, $data);
```

When I curl the image I get `<?php echo "ABC";?>`. Why is it just printing the string I passed to it rather than `ABC`

This is for a security lab I'm running locally so I'm using it as a PoC for this exploit e.g. https://blog.sucuri.net/2016/10/backdoor-abusing-of-php-tricks.html and https://www.exploit-db.com/papers/45870

I'm aware it won't get executed when viewing the file but shouldn't the PHP I sent in the body get interpreted and that be placed in a file so I should be seeing `ABC` rather than `<?php echo "ABC";?>`.

Another (better) example: https://www.aptive.co.uk/blog/local-file-inclusion-lfi-testing/

Thanks

Comment: You're feeding `file_get_contents()` with unsanitised input, nothing prevents the user from passing a file system path. Reading local files won't parse them as PHP code.

Comment: Have you set up your webserver to parse PHP when accessing `.jpg` files?

Comment: Added updates to this

Comment: https://www.aptive.co.uk/blog/local-file-inclusion-lfi-testing/ is a better example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard configuration of a web server is to execute PHP directives *only* in files with a `.php` file extension.

You could configure your web server to execute PHP in files with a `.jpg` file extension (the specifics depend on which web server you are using) but this would be highly unusual — doubly so because a JPEG image is a binary file and not a text file to start with.

---

Also note that allowing arbitrary PHP to be accepted as user input and then executed on your server is **highly** dangerous.

---

> I'm aware I won't get executed when viewing the file but shouldn't the PHP I sent in the body get interpreted?

No. Reading a file into a variable **only** reads a file into a variable. `file_get_contents` does not execute PHP directives in user input.

That would also be **highly** dangerous and PHP isn't that bad.

Comment: This is for a PoC for this exploit to show that this is indeed vulnerable.  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because a `.jpg` isn't a `.php` file, so by default it won't be executed by the PHP interpreter. Therefore you'll just get the raw content of the file.

(In theory you could configure your webserver to make it pass anything with a `.jpg` extension to PHP, but I don't recommend as it's quite likely to make it more difficult to access actual image files, or at least slow down their processing. I can't think of a sensible use case where what is supposed to be an image format would need to go via the PHP engine).

---

Re your update:

> shouldn't the PHP I sent in the body get interpreted?

...no. It's being held in a string variable (`file_get_contents` simply returns the raw content of the file). The PHP interpreter does not evaluate it - in fact at the time the code is interpreted (i.e. before it's executed) then the value doesn't even exist (obviously, because the variable cannot be populated until the code is executed).

If you had written either

```
$data = file_get_contents($image_url);
exec($data);
```

or

```
include($image_url);
```

then it's very likely the code in the file would be interpreted, incorporated into the main script, and executed. That *would* be a big vulnerability. You should absolutely *never* do this with either code provided directly from an external input, or by allowing the external input to specify which code file or snippet should be evaluated or included.

(N.B. The above techniques still wouldn't cause the "ABC" string to be placed into the output file, though. It would cause the code to be executed, and "ABC" to be output as the result of the script directly.)

Comment: This is for a PoC for this exploit to show that this is indeed vulnerable.  I have updated my question.

Comment: @pee2pee see the extension to the question. As a friendly hint, in future, please do ask about what you actually mean in the first place :-)

Comment: I was pretty clear I thought

Comment: Not really...it looked like you were asking why it wasn't executed when you viewed the jpg (because you said `When I curl the image I get <?php echo "ABC";?>`). That's why two of us answered as we did. Anyway please see the latest version, to address what you've added to the question.

Comment: I mean yeah, it was kinda clear. Yeah, using curl is not the same as viewing. Anyway...

Comment: `using curl is not the same as viewing`  yes, it is. Viewing the file in a browser or using curl...the server would treat the request in the exact same way. The server does not care  (or really know for sure, even) which type of client makes the request to it - it simply receives a HTTP request, and responds to it.

Comment: No. If I viewed the image in the browser, it would be corrupt. If I did a curl, it would show the text.

Comment: `If I viewed the image in the browser, it would be corrupt`...Well you'd just get a blank image. But that's not the point. The _server_ will deal with the request the exact same way (by just returning the raw content (valid JPG data or otherwise) and not executing the PHP code inside it). What you see after a curl request depends on what you make the receiving environment do with the data it receives. Curl itself doesn't display anything directly. So in terms of your question, viewing and curl-ing are effectively the same.

Comment: No, disagree but here we are

Comment: In what way do you disagree, specifically? Perhaps I can clarify something for you?

Comment: No, it's ok, have a good day